# How to read text and image from html?

Tags: android, html

How to read all text and images from a html page for example

http://wireless.ign.com/articles/118/1186400p1.html

Lets say i would like to get the text on the page, and the Latest images?

How would i go about doing this?

via HTTPGET Request? If so how?

How can i get this text and then do something with it and the images, like set it to a text view, and set the images to ImageView.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Comment: http://www.blogjava.net/pengo/archive/2011/03/14/346176.html

Comment: Could you provide a example in my situation?

Comment: please continue with this link, if you get any problem then post on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code in unix/linux
wget http://wireless.ign.com/articles/118/1186400p1.html -O test.html

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpURLConnection to get the html, and then use Regex or something like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) or similar to parse the Html.